# Ignore a line while reading a file in java

Tags: java

I have some code to read the lines from  a file, I would like to recognize when the line starts or the fisrt character (not blank) is '`*`' and ignore it, so inside the while statement add something like

```
if(line[0]=='*') 
   ignore that line
```

I have something like:

```
   input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(finaName)));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] words = line.split(" "); 
        .... 
    }
```

How to complete the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(finaName)));
String line = null;
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
  if(line.trim().indexOf('*') == 0)
    continue;
  String[] words = line.split(" "); 
    .... 
}
```

Comment: do you mean `line.trim()`? :-)

Comment: @glowcoder: probably. I think I communicated my intent though.  I'll update my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @asgs Apparently, Python gets more action than Java!!

Comment: absolutely it did. With an upvote from me :-) I strongly favor the use of well-formatted `continue` statements. I understand they are abused by junior programmers, but when used properly (as here) they make for very clean, clear flow-of-control structures.

Answer (score 2):

Change your while loop as:

```
while((line = input.readLine()) != null){
   if(!line.startsWith("*")){
      String[] words = line.split(" ");
      ....
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

If "*" is not in the beginning of the line but at some position in the line, use the following

```
if(line.indexOf("*") == position){
   ......
}
```

where position can be an integer specifying the position you are interested in.

Comment: One question, If in my file the '`*`' is lets say in position `n` and not at the very begining? How to add that cases

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the * marks and end of line comment, this loop will keep anything needed on the line before it.

```
    input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(finaName)));
    String line = null;
    char[] lineChars;
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        lineChars = line.toCharArray();
        line = "";
        for(char c: lineChars){
            if(c == '*')break;
            line.concat(Character.toString(c));
        }
        if(!line.equals(""))
        String[] words = line.split(" ");           
    }
```